# Determine if files are part of any package

Tags: bazel, build-system

Given I have a list of files, e.g `foo/src/main.cpp, foo/src/bar.cpp, foo/README.md` is it possible to determine which of those files are part of a bazel package?
In my example, the output would e.g. be `foo/src/main.cpp, foo/src/bar.cpp` since the README.md would not be part of the build.

One way to do this would be to call `bazel query` on each file and see if it results in an output, but that is quite inefficient and so I was wondering if there is an easier way.

**Background:** I am trying to determine if a changes in a set of files have an impact on a target, and I want to use `bazel query somepath(//some/target, set($FILES))` for that, but this will fail if any of the files in `$FILES` is not part of a BUILD file.

Answer (score 1):

How about flipping it around and querying for all the source files of the target with:

```
bazel query 'kind("source file", deps(//some:target))'
```

and then checking if the result has any of the files in the set